# What do I build in .Net to automatically generate a file every morning?

Tags: c#, .net, service, automation

I normally work directly in .aspx web files, but we have a need to generate files automatically every morning for use by the website and other processes.

The process of generating the day's files needs to run whether or not website is accessed. 
Process: at 6am every morning, get database dataset and generate files from it.

What is the best and most simplistic way to do this? Wcf service? asmx web service? something i haven't heard of?

Comment: Scheduled task with powershell.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Quartz Scheduler .Net, awesome library for CRON.

Comment: It is a duplicate. When I was typing the question it never came up in the list of possible suggestions... :(

Answer (score -1):

You can create a separate project within your solution and execute its exe with a scheduled task.

Comment: I would add that an application that runs in this mode should probably just be a consle application and nothing fancier than that.